# Matlab: add vector to matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, addition

I have a `3XN` matrix representing a list of 3D coordinates,something like

```
33    33    33    33    34    34    34    34    34    35    35
17    18    19    20    16    17    18    19    20    16    17
10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

I want to shift all coordinates by some vector `v=[1 2 3]`, that is add the 3D vector to each column of the matrix.

I know how to do that with a `for` loop, but how can I do it without a loop? Surely there's a way...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
D=[33    33    33    33    34    34    34    34    34    35    35;
17    18    19    20    16    17    18    19    20    16    17;
10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10 ];

A=[1 2 3]';

C= bsxfun(@plus, D, A)

C =

    34    34    34    34    35    35    35    35    35    36    36
    19    20    21    22    18    19    20    21    22    18    19
    13    13    13    13    13    13    13    13    13    13    13
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `repmat`:

```
M = randn(3, N);           % your 3 x N matrix
v = randn(3, 1);           % your vector
r = M + repmat(v, [1 N]);  % add v to every column of M
```

Comment: I think Nasser's answer is better - I think here you create a second matrix out of `v`, which would take a lot of space if `N` is very big, while his doesn't take up any extra space. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are probably right.  I'm partial to my solution because I have used it many many times :)  Unless N is VERY large, your computer is very slow, or you are repeating this operation a very large number of times, the difference in performance is probably negligible.  If performance isn't an issue, then I feel that using repmat might lead to slightly more readable and maintainable code.  But that is just an opinion.  Both solutions work :)

Comment: It's worth noting that `repmat` is very slow and that if `N` is large, then your solution will probably use much more memory. Also, `bsxfun` will work better with any multi-threading that may be available, e.g. via PCT.